# Finding the days in a month with leap year in Java

Tags: java

I am taking a class in java and and my program has to ask the month and the year and yell how many days are in the month. but I'm stuck on the leap year. 
This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class month {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter month, 1-12: ");
        int month  = input.nextInt();
        if (month > 12)
            System.out.print("Invalid month " + month);

        else        
            System.out.print("Enter a year: ");


        int year = input.nextInt();



    switch (month * 1){
    case 1: System.out.print("January " + year); 
    System.out.print(" has 31 days."); break;
    case 2: System.out.print("February " + year); 
    System.out.print(" has 28 days."); break;
    case 3: System.out.print("March " + year); 
    System.out.print(" has 31 days."); break;
    case 4: System.out.print("April " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 30 days."); break;
    case 5: System.out.print("May " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 31 days."); break;
    case 6: System.out.print("June " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 30 days."); break;
    case 7: System.out.print("jJuly " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 31 days."); break;
    case 8: System.out.print("August " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 31 days."); break;
    case 9: System.out.print("September " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 30 days."); break;
    case 10: System.out.print("October " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 31 days."); break;
    case 11: System.out.print("November " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 30 days."); break;
    case 12: System.out.print("December " + year);
    System.out.print(" has 31 days.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know if a year is a leap year?

Comment: `switch(month * 1)` any reason to multiply by one?

Comment: Read the section here on the algorithm for determining if it's a leap year.  It should be easy to incorporate:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Calendar`? Trying to work with dates manually is a big no-no outside of the classroom.

Comment: From 1901 to 2099, a year is a leap year if it's evenly divisible by 4.

Answer (score -1):

For the leap year:

```
case 2: System.out.print("February " + year); 
        if(isLeapYear(year)) {
            System.out.print(" has 28 days."); break;
        } else {
            System.out.print(" has 29 days."); break;
        }

// ...
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for writing the whole code for a student. Thanks also for not letting OP learning on its own and doing all the work. Seriously, thanks for helping to create a new zombie coder.

Comment: So much for "teaching them to fish".

Comment: Seriously, between wikipedia and 3 lines of simple code, there is not much difference

Comment: So, you also can't count to 3, since `isLeapYear` is more than three lines of code. Cool.